# How to enter user and password for WebDAV server on LibreOffice?

Tags: linux, libreoffice, libreoffice-writer, webdav

I am trying to configure a NextCloud WebDAV remote location on LibreOffice Writer 7.0 following these instructions: https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/shared/guide/digitalsign_receive.html

I am using the snap package on Linux Mint.

Despite correctly enabling `Use LibreOffice dialogs` and introducing the host, port 443, check `secure connection`, label, and root, after clicking "Ok" I don't get prompted for introducing my username and password, I don't see a list of files, and in general it's not clear what to do.

I also don't understand why the instructions mention "Website Certified by an Unknown Authority". I use a remote host that's perfectly verified with Let's Encrypt.

I tried to see if I could launch LibreOffice Writer with some sort of logging or debugging information, but https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Development/How_to_debug I don't have that much patience to setup gdb, compile a debugging build and so forth.

(xref: https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/287514/how-to-enter-user-and-password-for-webdav-server/)

Answer (score 0):

Despite what the documentation says, I managed to get the user/pass prompt when saving the file to that remote location.